# How can I remove, add and update using Entity Framework in single method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have Parent-Children structure in one of my functionality. I am using EF6.

I am able to add/update children records successfully but want to delete some of children records from db that got deleted from UI. Below is what I tried so far..

```
using (dbBlinkContext dbContext = new dbBlinkContext())
{
    // Add/Update Parent
    if (entity.parentID <= 0)
        dbContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
    else
        dbContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

    // Here I want to remove Children that got deleted from UI
    var dbChildren = dbContext.Children.Where(x => x.ParentID == entity.ParentID).ToList();     
    // this code is not working
    dbChildren.RemoveAll(c => !entity.Children.Contains(c)) // breaks here saying dbChildren not part of entity...

    // Add/Update Children
    if (entity.Children.IsNotNull() && entity.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ChildType child in entity.Children)
        {
            if (Child.ChildID <= 0)
                dbContext.Entry(Children).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
            else
                dbContext.Entry(Children).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
   }

  dbContext.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to remove the Children from a list, but you need to either remove them from entity.Children, or remove them from dbContext.Children.

Assuming that entity.Children is not null and contains the children you want to keep, instead of "dbChildren.RemoveAll(c => !entity.Children.Contains(c))", try:

```
dbContext.Children.RemoveRange(dbChildren.Except(entity.Children));
```